# Why does unix link not appear in browser?

Tags: html, unix

I have created a link of file stored elsewhere in public_html directory and want to access it through the web. But When I am opening the directory in web, it does not contain the link to original file but it does contain all the files stored in public_html. How will the browser show the link to the stored file or any other approach to access the stored file?

Comment: Even if the link would appear, fi it isn't in your htdocs, how would you access it?

Comment: htdocs is "public_html" in this case.

Comment: Sorry misread that as "elsewhere than in public_html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you need to configure your webserver to [follow symlinks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options).